# Sharing mutable global variable in Python multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I'm trying to update a shared object (a `dict`) using the following code. But it does not work. It gives me the input `dict` as an output.

**Edit**: Exxentially, What I'm trying to achieve here is to append items in the data (a list) to the dict's list. Data items give indices in the dict.

**Expected output**: `{'2': [2], '1': [1, 4, 6], '3': [3, 5]}`
Note: Approach 2 raise error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

1. **Approach 1**

   ```
   from multiprocessing import *
   def mapTo(d,tree):
           for idx, item in enumerate(list(d), start=1):
               tree[str(item)].append(idx)

   data=[1,2,3,1,3,1]
   manager = Manager()
   sharedtree= manager.dict({"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]})
   with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
       pool.starmap(mapTo, [(data,sharedtree ) for _ in range(3)])
   ```
2. **Approach 2**

````
 from multiprocessing import *
 def mapTo(d):
         global tree
         for idx, item in enumerate(list(d), start=1):
             tree[str(item)].append(idx)

 def initializer():
      global tree
      tree = dict({"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]})
 data=[1,2,3,1,3,1]
 with Pool(processes=3, initializer=initializer, initargs=()) as pool:
     pool.map(mapTo,data)```
````

Comment: Instead of sharing a dict between processes which is a bad idea, return a dict from each process and merge them afterwards.

Comment: why sharing a dict is a bad idea? In my case, a dict, which is kind of hash table, is really huge and I don't think returning a dict make sense.

Comment: Also, all processes are supposed to append items in the dict's list. I'm not worried about race condition here since a `Manager`'s list can be updated independently by subprocesses.

Comment: Sharing data structures between separate processes is kind of tricky. It can certainly be done, but to @JoshuaNixon point, make sure there isn't an easier way to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: Approach 2 raises error because it calls `mapTo` and in each call it passes an individual element of list

Comment: @Z4-tier. Using `Manager` we can easily share data structures.  Why is it tricky to be specific?

Comment: @Raj. Will it work if I make `chunksize=3` or more?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Will moving `tree =...` within initializer work?

Comment: Also don't do 'from multiprocessing import *' (i assume you just typed up a quick example in an interpreter shell, but still...)

Comment: you mean approach 2 is better but still some issue is there. Is there any possibility to make this work using `Manager` somehow? I don't know.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I moved `tree=` within initializer as also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778187/multiprocessing-pool-with-a-global-variable/18779028?noredirect=1#comment108820250_18779028) but same error.

Comment: The problem is that you are mutating the lists inside your managed dict, but that isn't going to work unless they are managed lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga approach 1 with your suggested modification `sharedtree= manager.dict({"1":manager.list(),"2":manager.list(),"3":manager.list()})` not yielding expected o/p.

Comment: @chandresh what is your expected output? What output are you seeing?

Comment: I'm not using `init==main` thing. My o/p is same as i/p.

Comment: @chandresh see my answer. Try it on your machine. Please show your output, edit your question and add it.

Comment: @chandresh What is the use of `[(data,sharedtree ) for _ in range(3)]` inside `starmap` in approach 1?

Comment: @Raj you are free to modify code to make it work. I thought it will pass shared tree to 3 processes but it will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use managed lists if you want the changes to be reflected. So, the following works for me:

```
from multiprocessing import *
def mapTo(d,tree):
        for idx, item in enumerate(list(d), start=1):
            tree[str(item)].append(idx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data=[1,2,3,1,3,1]

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        manager = Manager()
        sharedtree= manager.dict({"1":manager.list(), "2":manager.list(),"3":manager.list()})
        pool.starmap(mapTo, [(data,sharedtree ) for _ in range(3)])

    print({k:list(v) for k,v in sharedtree.items()})
```

This is the ouput:

```
{'1': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6], '2': [2, 2, 2], '3': [3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5]}
```

Note, you should always use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard when using multiprocessing, also, avoid starred imports...

#### Edit

You have to do this re-assignment if you are on Python < 3.6, so use this for `mapTo`:

```
def mapTo(d,tree):
        for idx, item in enumerate(list(d), start=1):
            l = tree[str(item)]
            l.append(idx)
            tree[str(item)] = l
```

And finally, you aren't using `starmap`/`map` correctly, you are passing the data three times, so of course, everything gets counted three times. A mapping operation should work on each individual element of the data you are mapping over, so you want something like:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import *
def mapTo(i_d,tree):
    idx,item = i_d
    l = tree[str(item)]
    l.append(idx)
    tree[str(item)] = l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data=[1,2,3,1,3,1]

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        manager = Manager()
        sharedtree= manager.dict({"1":manager.list(), "2":manager.list(),"3":manager.list()})
        pool.map(partial(mapTo, tree=sharedtree), list(enumerate(data, start=1)))

    print({k:list(v) for k,v in sharedtree.items()})
```

Comment: o/p from your code is `{'2': [], '1': [], '3': []}`.

Comment: @chandresh I cannot reproduce. I'm getting the output above. Are you sure you are running this *exact* code?

Comment: yes. I copy pasted your code and run in spyder with py 3.5. Besides, your o/p is not my expected o/p as shown in the question at the top.

Comment: @chandresh yes, that is because you are using the `pool.map` incorrectly. But that's sort of irrelevant to your issue. The problem is that you cannot nest managed objects in Python 3.5 easily, you ahve to do a seemingly redundant re-assignment. You really should probably upgrade...

Comment: hmm. seems like assignment to dict's list in py 3.5 is 3 line code.

Comment: @chandresh yes, again, you should really upgrade, but it fixes your problem. Now, *another* issue is how you are using `map`, you are passing the data three times, so of course, everything gets counted three times.

Comment: Got it. I made two changes 1. 3 line assignment in py 3.5 and 2. `pool.starmap(mapTo,[(data, sharedtree)])`. It gives expected output. Thanks a lot. You saved 15.5 hours my quarantine hard work.

Comment: @chandresh don't use `pool.starmap(mapTo,[(data, sharedtree)])` that defeats the entire purpose of multiprocessing, your data only has one element, so it will only ever use 1 process in your pool, you might as well just forget multiprocessing. Look at my final edit

Comment: sure. one small comment: Even this line works `sharedtree = manager.dict({"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]})`. I mean `Manager` need not manage nested list.

Comment: @chandresh yes, that's true. I haven't really used a manager pre-3.6

Comment: Hi, two Q. 1. Why iteration over data inside `mapTo` does not work? Does not manager assigns a block of data to each process so that I can iterate over? 2. How do I know one line assignment of append in dict's list in py 3.5 is not going to work. Reason behind it works in py 3.6+?

Comment: One more Q. Replacing `map` with `imap` does not work. Why so?