# Efficient implmentation of Python multiprocesssing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two codes. One is pooled (multiprocessing) version of the other. However, the parallel version with even 1 processor is taking a long time whereas the serial version finishes in ~15 sec. Can someone help to accelerate the second version.

1. **Serial**

```
    import numpy as np, time
    def mapTo(d):   
        global tree
        for idx, item in enumerate(list(d), start=1):
            tree[str(item)].append(idx)

    data=np.random.randint(1,4, 20000000)
    tree = dict({"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]})
    s= time.perf_counter()
    mapTo(data)
    e = time.perf_counter()
    print("elapsed time:",e-s)
```

takes: ~15 sec

2. **Parallel**

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import time

def mapTo(i_d,tree):
    idx,item = i_d
    l = tree[str(item)]
    l.append(idx)
    tree[str(item)] = l

manager = Manager()
data    = np.random.randint(1,4, 20000000)
# sharedtree= manager.dict({"1":manager.list(),"2":manager.list(),"3":manager.list()})
sharedtree = manager.dict({"1":[],"2":[],"3":[]})
s= time.perf_counter()
with Pool(processes=1) as pool:
    pool.map(partial(mapTo, tree=sharedtree), list(enumerate(data,start=1)))
e = time.perf_counter()
print("elapsed time:",e-s)
```

Comment: `l = tree[str(item)]; l.append(idx); tree[str(item)] = l` - what does that do? - get the value for a key which should be a list; append something to it; then assign it as the value for the key? - that last step seems unnecessary.

Comment: `d = {'1':list(np.where(data==1)[0]),'2':list(np.where(data==2)[0]),'3':list(np.where(data==3)[0])}` ??

Comment: I'd break assignment in 3 steps since one line assignment in an embedded list (dict's list) was not working in py 3.5. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518970/sharing-mutable-global-variable-in-python-multiprocessing-pool). Can't use the suggested sol since in Pool.map function, an iterable is passed  and function should be able to handle one data point.

Comment: The (non-concurrent) `mapTo` function takes 58 seconds on my computer. Whereas using np.where (my previous comment) takes about 1.3 seconds.  If that improvement is sufficient you can avoid multiprocessing.

Comment: Actually, I've put a simplified dict. In reality, it is 4 level nested dict where no of lists is around 200K. I'm inserting data to these lists and my data size is around 20M. My plan is to break the data, say in batches of 500K and run concurrently.